# gain with no side effects

Tags: analog, instrumentation-amplifier, biopotential

I want to see a signal `(5-25 microvolts  | 1-35HZ)` on my computer.but I dont know electronics so I just have one question:

I need to amplify THE signal to reach `0-5 V` for ADC.Does serialing two instrumentation amp like `AD620` or `AD8429` to get like 1M gain have any side effects?

or is there a better way to convert 5-25microvolts  to 0-5 V ?

Comment: The gain you need is only 5V/25mV = 200

Comment: @Botnic what? reallyy? I tried 100 but there was no signal on oscilloscope but when I added second 100 (serial) I saw the signal.P.S My bad its not mV its microvolts

Comment: Working with microvolt signals is always a challenge. I'd say that your input signal **must** be a differential signal , see here what that is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_signaling  Just cascading amplifiers can work but DC-offsets and noise are the side effects that will bug you. It is not something a beginner in electronics can do.

Comment: I think the side effect is that you are applying a lot of gain. This will amplify both signal and noise. 5uV is such a low signal that it will be difficult to distinguish from noise. On the other hand, your bandwidth is limited, so that is good. You can design your circuit to have low gain outside of your 1-35 Hz band.

Comment: @mkeith I agree with you but I also fear that the 1/f noise, which is more prominent at **low** frequencies, will be a problem. Maybe the solution could be a chopper stabilized amplifier.

Comment: @mkeith thats why after 1M gain I have a  highpass then a 16-order low-pass filter.I already saw my signal in oscilloscope just need to get the data

Comment: @FakeMoustache AD620 is differential i think and thats why im using it.

Comment: The AD620 is an instrumentation amplifier, that's a good choice. This amplifier has a differential input but you also need the circuit around it to use it that way (in a differential way I mean). It is also possible to use this amplifier in a single-ended way but I would not recommend that for your application.

Comment: @FakeMoustache im using it `that way (in a differential way I mean)`.what do you mean by single-ended?

Comment: Single-ended is the opposite/alternative to differential. The output of the AD620 is single-ended as it's output signal is between the output and ground (or negative supply rail). A true differential amplifier would have 2 output pins, outputting a differential signal. But don't worry about that, your input needs to be differential (which it is), the signal is amplified at the AD620's output so there is less need for a differential signal there.

Comment: @FakeMoustache is it possible to send differntial signal to micro ADC?

Comment: Most ADCs in microcontrollers are simple and only have a single-ended input. You cannot use those with differential signals. ADCs with differential inputs do exist though.

Comment: There is rarely cause to daisychain inamps.  The benefit of using an instrumentation amp is at the first stage.  Subsequent amplification should be done using op amps

Comment: @ScottSeidman im gonna use AD8429 with 100 gain then a 1028 with 2k gain.Do you its gonna be a problem?

Comment: @ScottSeidman do you have any suggestion about the first amp (instrumentation ) ? the best thing I saw was `AD8429` I cant find one with lower noise and lower input voltage offset.I really need the signal in 1-10 HZ frequency (5 uV) with no noise

Comment: Yes.  I don't know qhat a 1028 is, and a 2k gain will do bad things to offset voltages and your bandwidth.  Split the big gain up into a few op amp stages, and high pass filter after each one.

Comment: Also, a gain of 100 on the input might well saturate any offsets in electrode potentials.  I'd recommend no more than 20, and that might be high.

Comment: @ScottSeidman 20 gain then a 0.03 hz(enough or too much?) highpass again and again can remove the noise? where can I find the calculation?

Comment: this is [LT1028](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/1028fd.pdf) and anotherOne is [AD8597](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8597_8599.pdf). these are the best op amps I could find on google.

Comment: You have some fundamental misconceptions about the nature of the EMG signal.

Comment: There are always side effects!  I'd first worry about the DC offset of the amps.  AC couple as much as possible... that's harder with your low frequency range.  What's the source impedance of the thing you are looking at?  The AD620 has ~1nA of bias current which can ruin your day if you have a high input impedance.  You are also right in the range where the 1/f noise of the opamps is likely to dominate.   1/f noise is not nearly as well spec'ed as HF white noise, and can change a lot from piece to piece.  Can you post a circuit?

Comment: @ScottSeidman 2 years of study.I know whats EMG.im studying biomechanical engineering.Im working on deep muscles for my  research

Comment: @GeorgeHerold input is from skin.[this](http://www.electro-tech-online.com/attachments/ecg-3-png.68573/) is A circuit

Comment: @ScottSeidman I need 1-30 HZ frequencies only I dont need higher for now. I just need to know how does the noise change my signal so I can put suitable filter.

Comment: Funny, I teach BME, and I've been recording EMG for many years. http://faculty.educ.ubc.ca/sanderson/courses/HKIN473/pdf/ISEK_EMG-Standards.pdf   says 10Hz-450Hz, but I'll say the low end is a little high for me and the high end is a little low, but it's certainly near the range for striated muscle.  For "deep muscle", http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021929096845477 goes from 10-500 Hz.  The envelope of the signal may well have the freq range you want.  I suggest http://ece.eng.wayne.edu/~apandya/ECE7995/Winter2009-Team3/html/emg_0.html

Comment: @Lucifer, got it... that is not high impedance.  (Well what's in the patient protection gizmo... Maybe 1 meg ohm resistors?)    You may want to re-ask this question and put something about ECG in the title.  (It's not something I have done.)

Comment: @ScottSeidman  the articles are perfect thank you. im in a third-world country undergraduating biomedical(biomechanical). EMG has 4-10 HZ too and I need it for my project.I already saw EMG on oscilloscope with two AD620 with 1k gain.can you help me with what should I read to learn how much noise does `1 nV/√Hz input noise
45 nV/√Hz output noise ` make and how to counter it?

Comment: Can you edit your question, or start a new one, describing EXACTLY what you're trying to accomplish, starting with the muscles you're trying to record from, and ending with what you plan to do with the signals after you acquire them?  Assuming that you're actually needing to rectify and low pass filter, which is the traditional EMG treatment, the noise will just add to the output floor, and you can still see muscle changes despite noise.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's all about competing or living with noise.

A reasonable op-amp will have an equivalent input voltage noise of about 10 nV \$/\sqrt{Hz}\$ and if you implement a 1st order low pass filter having a 3 dB point of 40 Hz, the [**equivalent noise bandwidth**](http://www.onmyphd.com/?p=enbw.equivalent.noise.bandwidth&ckattempt=1) will be about 63 Hz. A 2nd order filter will have an equivalent noise BW of 48 Hz as you might anticipate.

So, how much noise is the op-amp going to produce?

10 nV * \$\sqrt{63}\$ (equivalent input noise) = 0.08 uV RMS. Added to this you have to contend with 1/f noise and this, for an op-amp like the ADA4528, is only about 100 nVp-p (because it is designed that way).

So, can you live with a noise of about 0.1 uV RMS when your signal might be as low as 5 uV RMS (SNR = 34 dB)?

You could choose a better op-amp that has lower voltage noise and improve things by 2 or 3 times. You could even adopt techniques that band limit the signal to the frequency spectrum where it exists (think I.F. strips on radio receivers).

If your signal is from a high impedance source then you have further problems due to op-amp current noises and possibly thermal noise from your source impedance.

Lots of things to think about but if you are prepared to be realistic then you might get a decent enough solution. It's all about noise not gain. Gain is the easy thing, living with noise is the harder thing.

Comment: My signal range is `1-35 HZ`.and my amp is [AD620](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD620.pdf),after two AD620 im filtering with a RC highpass filter and a 16-order lowpass filter. I think I saw what I was  looking for.that was just noise?

Comment: It's just a matter of numbers and whether you use IAs or op-amps isn't really of much consequence the way you have phrased the question. You won't need a 16th order LPF - that is likely to be massive overkill. I'll adjust my numbers.

Comment: Is that noise present even when we use the op amp in differential mode? @Andy aka

Comment: what about [Lmp7731](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmp7731.pdf) ?

Comment: That looks a decent device to maybe give you a gain of at least 10,000 but watch the input bias currents possibly giving you an offset voltage on the output. Why do you need to go differential with this do you think - there will be a slight bit more noise differential due to input resistors plus it's harder to control gain. Tell me what your input signal is please.

Comment: Does that imply differential? I guess it does.

Comment: yes.But not for the second one(second amp)

Comment: Agreed. You might also need to keep an eye on the worst case offset voltage of the front end amplifier. At a gain of maybe 10,000 the offset could be quite high especially if temperature is factored in. Probably not a problem though.

Comment: [LT1028](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/1028fd.pdf) is this good? what should I look for in datasheets? low bias input and low i/o noise?

Comment: That's a good device. Current noise is only a problem when you have significant impedances in your input lines but I don't think this will be a problem. Concentrate on voltage noise, offset voltage and bandwidth first but make sure input bias currents don't "develop" a voltage across input resistors that when multiplied by gain cause a big offset on the output. AC coupling between 1st stage and 2nd stage is a good idea to prevent this being a problem.

Comment: @Lucifer -- your signal range is NOT 1-35Hz if you are doing electromyography.  The signal range for EMG is about 50Hz to about 2kHz.  Many people take the ENVELOPE of that signal, but you still need to acquire it at full bandwidth and then process it.

Comment: @ScottSeidman good call but I'm not altering my numbers again LOL!